# mysql sql weird issue？

Tags: mysql, sql

return multiple data

why?

mysql sql :

```
 select * from t_book where id=(select round(max(id)*rand()) from t_book)
```

Comment: id is not unique

Comment: Short to the point and baffling. Would you like to explain what you are trying to achieve sample data?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Tarek you might have duplicated id values. To find out which you can run this query:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) c FROM t_book GROUP BY id HAVING c > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that "id" is a unique primary key value, it shouldnt return multiple values. In the returned values do all of the "id" fields match, or is it returning multiple varying ids?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your id column's uniqueness.

```
select round(max(id)*rand()) from t_book
```

This will return various number of ids, at least in mysql 5.6. I don't know why, but it's really weird.

You can try this, for selecting a random record from your table:

```
select * from t_book order by rand() limit 1;
```

If you stick with this round-max-random method, keep in mind that round can return 0 too and it's unlikely that you have a 0 id.

---

First I thought this is caused by duplicate id values. You can try this fiddle, and see what happens: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fc510/1.
For multiple runs I got 0, 1 or 2 result records.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Syntax error,
The function Round takes the form:

ROUND(N,[D]);